# How to copy columns from closed workbook to new workbook using VBA?

Tags: vba

Right now, I'm creating a new workbook with 12 column names all in row 1 and every time I run my macro to test it, the workbook has a different name (Book1, Book2,....)

I want to get specific columns from a CLOSED workbook and paste them to different columns in this new workbook.  I do NOT want to use the GetValuesFromAClosedWorkbook because in my macro, the user is picking the file ("Y:...\Test.xls").

I have the following code which works, but is not as automated as I would like it to be because I will not know the name of the workbook...whether if it's Book1, Book2, and so on...AND because it's opening the file, which I don't want it to do.

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:="Y:\......\Test.xls"
Range("D3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Book1").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
```

Is it possible that once the user picks the file, I can pick certain columns and paste them to this new workbook?

Any help will be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Does the workbook **have** to be closed? You cant just turn off screenupdating while you open the workbook and copy the columns?

Comment: @TimWilliams I suppose it doesn't have to be off and I could do that...but how would I fix the other problem where I'm specifying the added workbook name and instead, perform the code on the added workbook, no matter what the name is?

Comment: There is the workbook where I'm running the macro (AutomateFiles.xlsm) and the new workbook added (Book1, Book2,....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open a workbook you can do this:

```
Dim wb as WorkBook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("filepathhere")
```

Or when you add a new workbook:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add()
```

You can then use the reference `wb`:

```
Dim rngCopy as Range
Set rngCopy = wb.Sheets(1).Range(.Range("D3"), .Range("D3").End(xlDown))

wb2.Sheets("sheetname").Range("B2").Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngCopy.Value
```

Where `wb` is the file you opened and `wb2` is the newly-added workbook.

Using a "helper" sub to perform the copying:

```
Sub DoCopy(rngFrom as Range, rngTo as Range)
    Dim rngCopy as Range
    Set rngCopy = rngFrom.Parent.Range(rngFrom,rngFrom.End(xlDown))
    rngTo.Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count).Value = rngCopy.Value
End Sub
```

If you want to copy both values and formats:

```
Sub DoCopy(rngFrom As Range, rngTo As Range)
    rngFrom.Parent.Range(rngFrom, rngFrom.End(xlDown)).Copy
    rngTo.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    rngTo.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
'updated to copy values to first empty row (NOTE: all copied columns
'   must be the same length)
Dim shtDest as Worksheet
Set shtDest= wb2.Sheets("sheetname")

DoCopy wb.Sheets(1).Range("D3"), shtDest.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).end(xlUp).offset(1,0)
DoCopy wb.Sheets(1).Range("G3"), shtDest.Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).end(xlUp).offset(1,0)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This definitely helps!

Comment: So sorry to keep asking but I'm having one last issue.  I understand your code when I open one file and paste the values but what would I do if I have another file that I need to open and paste the values right after the last row pasted from the first file?  Say the rows end at 20 from file 1 and now I want to keep inserting right after row 20 (21 till the end of my data from file 2)...How would that be done?  My rows from file 1 can change so I wouldn't know the exact location, I would have to find it and then insert the same data types but from file 2...Last thing I need to create my file...

Comment: You mind me asking what the 2 means in the following code `shtDest.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2)`

Comment: I got the whole file built but I just noticed that the DoCopy is copying only values.  I've been searching everywhere to find a solution so it copies the values AND formatting and I can't find one with the way you have coded it.  Is there any way to fix this?   (Some of my values have a 0 in front - ex: 012345, and your code is getting rid of the 0 in front when pasting to the new workbook)

Comment: Your original question used pastespecial>values: that's why I coded it the way I did.  Do you just need a straight copy (which would also copy formulas), or a two-step pastespecial (values + formats) ?

Comment: I just noticed that I had only put values...my bad.  I just need it to copy the value and format so that 0 shows up in front of my numbers.  Is there an easy fix to your code to do that or would I have to change the whole code around?

Comment: Just noticed your edit! Amazing work yet again. Thank you thank you thank you